# How to write sumation in IBM CPLEX Python API

Tags: python, cplex

I am new to Cplex Python APIs, but I worked with Cplex OPL, in OPL, you can easily write this objective function Max [sum C_ij*X_ij] as:

Maximize
sum(i in set1,j in set2) C_ij*X_ij

if we want to use python API, we have to define it in vector format Max C*X, which C and X are both vectors of coefficients and variables respectively. So you need to make the vector format from C_ij matrix.

Is there any way to write it in matrix format like what we do in OPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CPLEX Python API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/help.html?pos=2) does not support this, but the [DOcplex Modeling for Python API](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/optimization-modeling/modeling-for-python/) is similar to OPL.  For a quick start to the later see the [Creating a MP model in a nutshell](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc/master/docs/mp/creating_model.html) page, and [Model.sum](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc/master/docs/mp/docplex.mp.model.html#docplex.mp.model.Model.sum) in the reference manual.

Comment: I just want to rephrase what you said. Cplex Python API only support 1 dimention vecor, and if we want to write a_ijk we cannot use 3-dimentiolan array, and we need to comvert it to 1-dimentional vector?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.  With the CPLEX Python API, there are the [SparsePair](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._matrices.SparsePair-class.html) and [SparseTriple](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._matrices.SparseTriple-class.html) classes to represent sparse matrices, but you would build these with one dimensional lists.

Comment: You were so helpful. Last question. Is it possible to create model in OPL and save it as a LP model file, then call or use this model in Python. i.e. write the model in OPL and give the input parameters in Python?

Comment: Yes, you can [export to an LP](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplide/topics/opl_ideref_intell_ed_lped_export_to_lpfile.html) file from within the OPL IDE.  Keep in mind, though, that you can loose precision when exporting to the LP format.  You might select SAV format instead.  From the CPLEX Python API, you can [read](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex.Cplex-class.html?view=kc#read) in one of these models very easily.

Comment: I do appreciate if you can answer this question as well. I build my model and at the end I just type "Model.solve()" and I get this error:
"CPLEX DLL not found: please provide DOcplexcloud credentials"

I have CPLEX Studio 12.6 installed on my pc. and I want to solve the problem locally not on cloud.

Comment: Please start a new question for that.  I think that goes beyond what can be reasonably be answered in a comment and is no longer related to the original topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just created the new post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41110243/5131569

Comment: Is it allowable to use two nested Model.sum. For example: 
Model.sum(x[j]*Model.sum(x[j] for j in j_range) for i in i_range)  ? thx